# UWP Map - get a MapElement under Pointer

Tags: uwp, uwp-maps

I have code that adds custom MapPolylines to the MapControl, to its MapElements collection. They are displayed fine, but is there a way to detect any MapPolyline which is currently under the Pointer? I want to be able to delete any single MapPolyline, not to clear the whole MapElements collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register for the MapElementPointerEntered event
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapelementslayer
or use FindMapElementsAtOffset
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapcontrol